# What subset of C is supported by Verifiable-C?

Tags: c, verifiable-c

I'm trying to figure out what subset of C is supported by Verifiable C from [Verified Software Toolchain](https://vst.cs.princeton.edu/). "Program Logics For Certified Compilers" (p. 143) states that it is subset of [Clight](https://www.academia.edu/download/48189187/a_3A102104590950520160819-23312-1k5qm6y.pdf). But [CompCert compiler](https://compcert.org/) transforms program from CompCert C to Clight. Does that mean that it is possible to verify any CompCert C program by Verifiable C?

Comment: Please provide some URLs for us un-enlighted to CompCert, Verifiable C, and so on. You don't want us to spend time to search for the correct ones, do you? Additionally, please tell us what you already tried to find out, including asking "them" who provide that resources.

Comment: I've found out that clightgen actually transforms C into Clight. Not sure what I should do now with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, using Verifiable C one first uses CompCert's parser/typechecker to transform C into Clight, so it's not really about "What's in C but not in Clight", it really is about "which features of C are not supported."  Page 9 of the [reference manual](https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/VST/raw/master/doc/VC.pdf) says, basically:

- Goto is not supported in Verifiable C (but CompCert supports goto).
- Struct-copy (by struct assignment, struct parameters) is not supported in Verifiable C (but I think it's supported in CompCert)
- Only structured switch statements (no Duff's device in either VC or CompCert)
- Can't cast pointers to integers then do arithmetic on the result.

Those are the main limitations.

Comment: Does that mean that it is harder to verify programs with goto (because one should verify transformed, not original program?

Comment: Source programs with goto cannot be verified using VST, at present.  The CompCert front-end translates these programs into Clight programs with goto, which Verifiable C cannot handle.

Comment: I guess it is possible to eliminate `goto` before running clightgen (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885890/4227829)). It just becomes even harder to verify such programs.

Comment: From what I understand, a major restriction in CompCertC is that objects of pointer type may only be accessed by lvalues of pointer type, *and not by lvalues of character type*.  This would make the language unsuitable for some purposes, but for many other purposes a statically-verifiable dialect would be more useful than one that can't be statically verified.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention above:  VST does not support bitfields.

Answer (score 0):

Verifiable C [manual](https://github.com/PrincetonUniversity/VST/blob/master/doc/VC.pdf) (see page 9) states that the instrument works with subset of C with number of restrictions. But *clightgen* tool that comes with CompCert installation translates C into CompCert’s Clight intermediate language, so the subset with which Verifiable C can work is almost entire C.

Comment: Since Verifiable C is a subset of Clight, Clight is a superset of Verifiable C. So Clight might have properties that prevent verification.